# params.merge instead of :overwrite_params gives different URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my old Rails 2.3 application I had something like:

```
link_to 'Portuguese', url_for(:overwrite_params => { :lang => 'pt' })
```

which was returning me URLs formatted as:

.../pt

Now that I've upgraded to Rails 3.0 `:overwrite_params` doesn't work any more, they say `params.merge` can be used instead to have the same result.
This is true, the page I land to is the same, yet

```
link_to 'Portuguese', params.merge(:lang => 'pt')
```

gives me URLs the kind of:

.../?lang=pt

How could I maintain the same URLs as before?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a match statement. In routes.rb file you need to mention something like

```
get "sign_up/:lang" => "users#new"
```

I tried this in console

```
1.9.3-p429 :001 > include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

1.9.3-p429 :011 > url_for(:only_path => true, :controller => 'users', :action = 'new' , :lang=>'pt')

=> "/sign_up/pt"
```

In this manner you will pass the parameter lang as '/pt' and not '/?lang=pt'

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I tried it myself (I was using optional routing before, like `get "sign_up(/:lang)" => "users#new"`) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this horrible-looking workaround working:

after defining a matching route

```
match '(/:lang)', to: 'home#index', as: :home
```

I create the link to it as:

```
link_to "Portuguese", URI(request.referer).path + "pt"
```